# How can I return my string in swift by using parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6

```
func getParse (className:String,key:String,dataName:AnyObject) -> (String)
{
    var result = String()
    var query = PFQuery(className: className)
    query.whereKey(key, equalTo: dataName)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Found")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    result = object[key] as! String
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error  \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
   return result
```

}

This is my function that can getting data from my class in parse database. I want to return that data in String but it returned nothing when I try to printed it.

Thank you for every comments.

Comment: That is an asynchronous call. `result` won't be set before the completion block is executed. Maybe there is a version of `findObjects` that is not `inBackground`?

Comment: Thank you, Let's I try it with new version.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an asynchronous call. You need to use findObjects(), but this will stay on the main thread. Why do you need to return a string? You could set a variable from within the completion block that could update a label on your view or something like that.

Edit: Since you are trying to set a label, you don't need to return the string, you should just set the label from within your completion block. This would modify you're given code as follows:

```
func getParse (className:String,key:String,dataName:AnyObject)
{
  var result = String()
  var query = PFQuery(className: className)
  query.whereKey(key, equalTo: dataName)
  query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("Found")
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
               // result = object[key] as! String
               self.textLabel.text = result // NEW CODE HERE
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Error  \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to get string from parse database and show it on my Label. Sorry if my answer isn't clear. I'm new about this field.

Comment: If you do self.label.text = result, that could set your label